# How to plot triangles using coordinates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some sample coordinates like (0,0) (0,1) (1,0). how can i Plot multiple triangles in a same graph in python using coordinates only ?

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0])
plt.plot([1,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1])
plt.plot([1.5,1.5,2.5,1.5],[1.5,2.5,1.5,1.5])
plt.show()
```

Note: plt.plot([enter each x's coordinates],[enter each y's coordinates]).
The first x and y coordinates are entered once again at the end of the list or the triangle won't close up.